# How to assign the Key & value for a hash table during run time in java

Tags: java, hashtable

I want to accept the key from the user during run time, save it in hash map & accept value for this key sometime later & save it in same hash table.

Comment: so first you want to save key in hashmap and later sometime you want to save value for key right? How do you know later for which key this value must be saved? @user

Comment: Insert key with a null value in the map. Later add the value to that key.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create key objet using user input and perform calculations and evaluate value out of it later on you can store it in hashmap as key value pair.

```
class InputTest{
 public static void main(String [] arg){
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   HashMap<String,String> map= new HashMap<>();
   for(int I=0; I<5;I++)
    { 
      String key = sc.nextLine();
      String Val= sc.nextLine();
     map.put(key,Val);
    }
System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```